# A question about the chapter 6 of jackson?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics

This is what explained in answer for part b of exercise of 6.1 of Jackson.

> *This represents a plane traveling in the positive x direction and a plane traveling in the negative x direction, both starting at x = 0. Beyond these planes, the field is zero. At the planes, the observation points are getting their first signal due to the flash of sheet charge. Between the planes, the observation points are receiving signals from lateral locations far away on the sheet charge. Because they are far away, their signal took longer to reach the observation point. Interestingly, even though each lateral source point is farther away and its signal is therefore weaker, there are an ever increasing number of lateral source points to compensate. As a result, the wake of the causality shell is constant. This is an artifact of an infinite sheet charge. In reality, a finite sheet charge means that eventually there are no more lateral points left to flash and the field will die down at a fixed point.*

Is it possible to explain it by more details about the geometric shape of the planes. I mean it looks like there should be signals in which are in the same distance from the observation point, consequently it should be a circular loop. Isn't it?

Comment: Can you include the question from Jackson?  It's hard to comment without knowing the question.

Comment: http://faculty.uml.edu/cbaird/all_homework_solutions/Jackson_6_1_Homework_Solution.pdf